# How do I solve this warning in my console in my reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, heroku, use-effect, get-mapping

My app works as expected but sometimes in my console i get this error that i don't know how to solve

[image]

Comment: you are making an XHR call that is resulting in a 500 from the server

Answer (score 0):

Use `promise.catch` clause or a `try/catch` block to handle server errors in your promise callbacks.

Comment: I think that the error is coming from the java API, in the console this is the error
 "JSON mapping problem: java.util.ArrayList[5]->com.ravtecnologia.desafio.models.Grupo["atividades"]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[5]->com.ravtecnologia.desafio.models.Grupo["atividades"])"